# PHPのPOSTの上限について

Tags: php

PHPプログラミング超初心者です。

勉強を主目的に、とある多数のチェック項目に対する記録をするサイトをcloud9とLaravelを使って作成しているのですが、1000を超えるデータをPOSTで送信できないです。
1001以上ある場合に、1000個までしかデータが送られてないです。(Controller内で、 `dd($request);` で確認しました)
いろいろ調べてphp.iniファイル内の `max_input_vars = 3000` にしましたが、1000個のデータしか遅れてないです。

どのようにしたら1000以上のデータがPOST出来るのか教えていただけないでしょうか
該当箇所のViewは以下のように、チェック項目数分データを取得して、 `foreach` で表示しています。

```
@foreach ($evidence as $a_evidence)
 <tr>
@if ($first == true)
<td>{!! Form::select('evidence_type[]',['null'=>'', 'strength'=>'+', 'weakness'=>'-', 'neutral'=>'±'],  $a_evidence->evidence_type, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}</td>
<?php $first = false; ?>
@endif
<td>{!! Form::textarea('evidence_comment[]', $a_evidence->evidence_comment, ['class' => 'form-control', 'rows' => '2']) !!}</td>
<td>{!! Form::text('evidence_document[]', $a_evidence->evidence_document, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: php.iniを変更した後、PHPをホストしているサービス(普通ならApache)の再起動はされましたか?

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。理由はよくわからないですが、上限のデフォルト変更できました。

Comment: 推測ですが、OOPerさんがおっしゃる通り、サービスの再起動が理由かと思われます。 `$ sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart` を実行後、機能は変化がなかったのですが、本日再度AWSを起動して確認したところ振る舞いが変わっていました。 AWSを一度シャットダウンしたことと、`$ sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart` 以外は何もしていないのですが、いずれにせよ、何かで設定が反映されたものと思われます。
微妙な解決になってしまいましたが、ありがとうございました。

Comment: @GK29 さん、ご報告ありがとうございます。とりあえず無事に変更が反映できたようで良かったです。このサイトでは自己解決した場合自己回答することが推奨されています。なかなか微妙な解決ということですが、コメント中に書いてある「実際にやって見たこと」を順に書き並べるだけでも、似た事象で困っている方々の役にたつと思います。ぜひともよろしくお願いします。

Comment: @OOPerさん。アドバイスありがとうございます。先ほど、とりあえずやったことを回答に記載させていただきました。他にも不備などあればご指摘いただければと思います。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。十分見やすく書けていると思います。もう「承認」ができるはず(回答の横のチェックマークっぽいもの)だと思うので、承認もお願いします。

Comment: 承認しました。気付けてなかったので、助かりました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

どこに問題があったか一部曖昧ですが、POSTのデフォルト値を変更したときに実施したことを記録しておきます

1. `$ sudo vi php.ini` でphp.iniを編集状態にする
2. `max_input_vars = 1000` を　`max_input_vars = 3000` に変更する
3. `$ sudo /etc/init.d/httpd restart` でApacheを再起動させる
4. ここで確認したが反映されず
5. PCをシャットダウン
6. 翌日再度確認したら、反映されてました